# How to remove system folders from Windows 7 Explorer Main Window (NOT the Navigation Pane)

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I'm old people proofing a laptop and trying to remove or hide these folders with a registry tweak. Anyone? Win 7 64 bit

[image: Desktop Icons (Recycle Bin, Control Panel)]

Comment: disable/hide explore too then? you could go so fas as to create virtual drive letter, mapp all the 'old-people friendly' folders to it, then setup explorer or some other file browser to only mount that virtual drive.  really put them in an aquarium.

Answer (score -1):

You can turn them on/off in **Control Panel > Personalization > Change Desktop Icons**

From there, simply uncheck the items that you wish to hide.

Comment: Those are already unchecked. They still appear in explorer. I can right click and 'delete' but the icons stay in the explorer window (they are gone everywhere else).